# What does “otherwise than” mean in this context

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, context

“The library, which I had never seen otherwise than wide open, was tight shut.”

Comment: ***otherwise than*** : 
*in any way except the way that you are mentioning*. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/otherwise-than

Comment: Has the character seen the library wide open before or not? I am so confused , sorry.

Comment: The character had always seen the library   wide open, apart from this time when they saw it shut.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Or just "other than..."

Comment: This sentence is in Charles Dicken’s amazing short story “ out of the season” and in the story he identifies that the character had never been in the town. Then, he came to the town and saw the library. That is why I was confused but it is much more clear now thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

otherwise = in the other way or differently

than = compared to something

otherwise than  = differently or in the other way compared to something

You never saw the library differently or in the other way compared to "wide open".

"differently/in the other way" modifies "saw"

differently from "wide open" means in the way that not wide open = **closed** or = opened with short distance

You never saw the library closed/in the other way before.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context, otherwise than means that the person has only seen the library open before, and is now seeing it closed.

Try replacing with 'other than'. They mean the same thing and are both grammatically correct, though 'otherwise than' embellishes the sentence a little more.

A few helpful links: [Glosbe definition](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwicrqGMhoruAhVfxzgGHYQFDWQQFjARegQINBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fglosbe.com%2Fen%2Fen%2Fotherwise%2520than&usg=AOvVaw2xQNlPdP_ANyR2Yoi1K0Rj), [Macmillan Dictionary definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/otherwise-than)